# How do I understand CascadeType keyword?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, cascade

I thought `CascadeType` keyword is associated with operation of `EntityManager`.
But these codes confuses me.
Code like following.(Sorry for really simple code)

```
Parent parent = new Parent();
Child child1 = new Child();
Child child2 = new Child();

parent.addChild(child1);
parent.addChild(child2);

em.persist(parent);
```

after run, parent, child1, child2 was inserted.
It' okay until here and this is I expected.

```
Parent foundParent = em.merge(parent); // parent has identifier
Child child1 = new Child();
Child child2 = new Child();

parent.addChild(child1);
parent.addChild(child2);
```

From here.. I started to think `em.perist != CascadeType.PERSIST`.

And.. this code was also same.

```
Parent foundParent = em.find(Parent.class, 1);
Child child1 = new Child();
Child child2 = new Child();

parent.addChild(child1);
parent.addChild(child2);
```

child1, child2 was also inserted.

Now I'm very confused.
If they're not same between `operation of EntityManager` and `CascadeType`, how can I understand `CascadeType.MERGE` as well?

Sorry for my short english, thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right in general, but the specifications (JPA 2.2, paragraph 3.2.4) also contain these rules:

> The semantics of the flush operation, applied to an entity X are as follows:
>
> - If X is a managed entity, it is synchronized to the database.
> - For all entities Y referenced by a relationship from X, if the relationship to Y has been annotated with the cascade element value cascade=PERSIST or cascade=ALL, the persist operation is applied to Y.

So, if a child is added to a managed parent, and the parent-child entity is annotated with cascade = PERSIST, then the child is inserted.

The specifications are freely available. They are what defines the behavior. So reading them is the way you can understand how JPA works.

Comment: It means that my situation is not from `persist` but from `flush`.. right? Looks like CascadeType.PERSIST has more role than others.

Comment: All situation can be explained from this specification. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Persist and merge are designed as a way to keep one managed instance of a certain object.

If you use persist it means the object does not exist yet, so making it a unique managed instance doesn't hurt.

When you use merge, you take into consideration that a managed instance of the object may already exist. You don't wanna replace that unique managed instance, because some other object might reference it, believing it is the managed object.

If you use merge on an outdated version of the object, which you passed as an argument to the previous merge, JPA doesn't know how to find the right object since it has yet no id. It is assumed that it is a new object and new managed instance will be created.

- **CascadeType.PERSIST** : cascade type presist means that save() or persist() operations cascade to related entities.
- **CascadeType.MERGE** : cascade type merge means that related entities are merged when the owning entity is merged.
- **CascadeType.REFRESH**: cascade type refresh does the same thing for the refresh() operation.
- **CascadeType.REMOVE**: cascade type remove removes all related entities association with this setting when the owning entity is
  deleted.
- **CascadeType.DETACH**: cascade type detach detaches all related entities if a “manual detach” occurs.
- **CascadeType.ALL** : cascade type all is shorthand for all of the above cascade operations.